# OpenVPN connection from within 2nd subnet in office?

Tags: openvpn, ip-routing

I have OpenVPN setup and working. My office is part of a large building that operates several VLANs. Obviously from within our own VLAN I can access local resources, and from somewhere else in the world I can use OpenVPN. But when connected to a different VLAN in the same establishment I cannot do either.

OpenVPN is complaining because it is connecting to the building's external IP address, but the reply is being routed back internally (by switches I have no control over), which means the reply is not from the expected IP. Result:

```
Incoming packet rejected from [AF_INET]10.67.5.1:1194[2], 
   expected peer address: [AF_INET]195.x.x.x:1194 
   (allow this incoming source address/port by removing
   --remote or adding --float)
```

(x.x.x = censored public ip)

Anyone help? (I realise this is similar to [other posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/227255/how-to-test-openvpn-connection-from-within-the-same-network/318368#318368) but I thought my problem was a bit different and justified a separate question)

As requested, server conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.67.15.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.67.5.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Client config

```
client
remote example.org
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client_rich.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client_rich.key
comp-lzo yes
dev tun
proto udp
nobind
auth-nocache
script-security 2
persist-key
persist-tun
user openvpn
group openvpn
```

Comment: Please edit your post to append the server and client configuration files.

Comment: What happens if you peer with 10.67... when you are on that network?

Comment: @quanta: have done.

Comment: @polynomial: 'peer with'?

Answer (score 6):

As it said, add a `float` option to the client config and try again.

```
--float
```

> Allow  remote  peer  to change its IP address and/or port number, such
> as due to DHCP (this is the default if **--remote** is not used).  **--float**
> when specified with **--remote** allows an OpenVPN  session to  initially
> connect  to a peer at a known address, however if packets arrive from
> a new address and pass all authentication tests, the new address will
> take control of the session.  This is useful when you are connecting
> to a peer which holds a dynamic address such as a dial-in user or DHCP
> client.
>
> Essentially, **--float** tells OpenVPN to accept authenticated
> packets from any address, not only  the address which was specified in
> the **--remote** option.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this with patchy results. Still testing. It appeared to be working for about 90seconds, though!